# How to determine a method is overridden or not from definition? (Objective-C/iPhone SDK 4))

Tags: objective-c, ios4

How to determine a method is overridden or not from definition? (Objective-C/iPhone SDK 4))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have to check the superclass.